# JavaScript Fibonacci Calculator: How to output answer into text box?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, fibonacci

I am currently trying to make a calculator that takes a numerical input (n) and shows the Fibonacci number to the nth sequence. I am a beginner at Javascript and just can't seem to make my code work:

```
HTML:
<head>
  <script src="calculator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" name="Input" value="" id="userInput" / >
    <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="calculate();" />
    <input type="number" name="Answer" id="userAnswer" />
</body>

JavaScript:

var input = document.getElementById("userInput");
var output = document.getElementById("userAnswer");
var answer;

function calculate(){
n = input.value;
if (n < 2){
  return 1;
} else {
  answer = calculate(n - 2) + calculate(n - 1);
  return answer;
}
output.value = answer;
}
```

Comment: You have some problems here. For one, you are recursively calling `calculate()` with an argument, but the function definition takes no parameters. Also, where you assign a value to `output.value`, that is unreachable code. You have an if/else, and in both branches you `return`. Therefore you can never reach the `output.value=answer;` line.

Comment: I also found that putting this script in `<head>`, the elements you are selecting in javascript don't exist yet. Put the `<script>` tag inside `<body>`, preferably at the end of the `<body>` section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Don't be complex!

```js
function calculate(n){
  if (n < 2){
    return 1;
  } else {
    return calculate(n - 2) + calculate(n - 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="calculator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" name="Input" value="" id="userInput" / >
    <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="document.getElementById('userAnswer').value=calculate(document.getElementById('userInput').value);" /><br>
    <input type="number" name="Answer" id="userAnswer" />
</body>
```

Comment: That was extremely helpful. I see that I was mixing my recursively called function with trying to set values. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TRiNE if i add input has 1000 then it freezes out. Any idea why it cannot handle 1000?

Comment: @james may be due to recursion limits. then you have to use an iterative approach instead of recursion.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @TRiNE